# ESRI ArcGIS routing API extremely slow compared to other providers

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm implementing a wrapper that requests route information from different geospatial / GIS API providers. Input is always two or more waypoints (latitude, longitude pairs).

It is not my goal to do a public benchmark or a comparison between different service providers. The problem is, it works pretty well with Google Maps, Bing maps and Here maps but requesting a route from Esri route API takes forever.

For all providers, I tried to optimize settings as far as I could:
- Limiting the requested output to geometry, time and distance
- Using just default driving modes (such as car, no real time information...)

EDIT:

Request URLs and response times (requested from Berlin, Europe) below. I executed the requests multiple times, even at different days and the times are almost the same. Coordinates are always Paris to Prague.

**Esri**: 46,26 seconds(!)

`https://route.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World/solve?f=json&returnDirections=false&token=<my_api_token>&stops=2.3522,48.8566;14.4378,50.0755`

**Bing**: 611 milliseconds

`https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving?key=<my_api_token>&ra=excludeItinerary,routePath&wp.1=48.8566,2.3522&wp.2=50.0755,14.4378`

**HERE**: 664 milliseconds

`http://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=<my_api_token>&mode=fastest%3Bcar&representation=display&waypoint0=geo!48.8566%2C2.3522&waypoint1=geo!50.0755%2C14.4378&jsoncallback=H.service.jsonp.handleResponse(5)`

**Google**: 92 milliseconds

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/DirectionsService.Route?5m4&1m3&1m2&1d48.8566&2d2.352200000000039&5m4&1m3&1m2&1d50.0755&2d14.437800000000038&6e0&12sen-US&23e1&callback=_xdc_._95pqrj&key=<my_api_token>
&token=117312`

Has anyone experienced the same? Do I miss any steps?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're testing using a large distance. Requests for shorter distances respond much more quickly (generally less than a second):

```
https://route.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World/solve?f=json&returnDirections=false&stops=-116.1957,34.0564;-118.184,34.0546&token=<my_api_token>
```

Right now (Oct 2018) if you know you're using long distances and want better performance, you can add the query parameter `overrides={"TopHierarchyLevel": 1}`. [Documentation here](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/network/api-reference/route-synchronous-service.htm#ESRI_SECTION3_51DAC931FD934D2F841430BB6774C6AC). In the future, this `overrides` parameter should not be necessary.

Adding that to your example, it should return in approx 7-9 seconds:

```
https://route.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World/solve?f=json&returnDirections=false&token=<my_api_token>&stops=2.3522,48.8566;14.4378,50.0755&overrides={"TopHierarchyLevel": 1}
```

Comment: Another update: When executing this as http POST, it seems that your parameter helps speeding up the request to 9 seconds as promised. Still, the response time is 10 times longer than for the competitor apis. Really no other option to achieve similar performance?

Comment: Does this parameter lead to reduced performance for short distance routes? Why wouldn't I always use this parameter to speed up any kind of route requests?

Comment: I think there are certain situations where using this parameter on short distance routes would yield a lower quality result.